# Error when using conditional statement with timestamp in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am performing the following:

```
create table test(id int not null, time timestamp with time zone);  
insert into test (id,time) values (1, case when 0=1 then '2016-07-27 11:53:16.908000 +03:00:00' end);
```

I get the following error from postgres:

```
ERROR:  column "time" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type text  
LINE 1: insert into test (id,time) values (1, case when 0=1 then '20...  
                                              ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `case` does not make any sense at all. What are you really trying to do there?

Answer (score 3):

Read the error message carefully, it tells you what the problem is: "*but expression is of type **text***"

You need to use a proper timestamp literal.

`'2016-07-27 11:53:16.908000 +03:00:00'` is a varchar (text) constant, not a timestamp value. To specify a timestamp value use:

```
timestamp '2016-07-27 11:53:16.908000 +03:00:00'
```

So your insert should look like this:

```
insert into test 
  (id,time) 
values 
  (1, case when 0=1 then timestamp '2016-07-27 11:53:16.908000 +03:00:00' end);
```

Comment: O.k...
And why is the timestamp is a special case?
Why the same thing with Int or Boolean works fine?

Comment: The fact that I should explicitly cast looks very strange to me for 2 reasons:  
1. If I am not using conditional statement just regular:  
    insert into test (id,lastLogingDate) values (1,'2016-07-27 11:53:16.908000 +03:00:00') , it works fine.
2. I am interacting with postgres through jdbc so actually I have a prepared statemend: insert into test(id,lastLoginDate) values (?, case when ?=1 then ?).  
    I have the following code on the client side:  
    conn.setInt(1,1)
    conn.setInt(2,0)
    conn.setTimestamp(3,new Timestamp(blah blah blah)).   
So why would I need to cast?

Comment: There is no "cast", this is how a proper timestamp literal is written. When you don't do that Postgres will try to implicitly convert your `varchar` constant to a `timestamp` which succeeds with the format given. The `case` expression has no default data type and therefor you need to supply a proper timestamp literal in the expression so that Postgres can determine it. Relying on implicit data type conversion is always a bad idea.

Comment: @EliGolin: you should have stated in your initial question that this is about a prepared statement. The most robust solution is probably to cast the _result_ of the `case` to a timestamp rather then the constant: `(case ... end)::timestamp`

Comment: Implicit data type conversion concerns **literals** not **expressions** (`case ... end` is an expression).

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name.
This is not a good solution for me since when I build the prepared statement string, I have no idea of the exact types so the construct  -  
`case when ?=1 then ?` should have been reused by various types.
I still don't understand why does it work properly with other sql types except of timestamp.

Comment: @klin: but it concerns the expression if it _contains_ literals

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't think so. It concerns literals, maybe inside an expression but then the rules of this expression are used. In other words, there are no backward cascading rules of implicit casting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
insert into test (id,time) 
select 1, case when 0=1 then '2016-07-27 11:53:16.908000 +03:00:00' ::timestamp end
```

However since in your case the condition is always false i.e, 0<>1 hence you can put a default value or a NULL value to your time column.

If you want you can put the default value when you are creating the table like

```
create table test(id int not null, 
times timestamp with time zone default now());
```

**On a side note:**

Try to avoid naming your column names which are [keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

Comment: Hii.. I've over simplified the problem just to present hte simplest case which fails.

Im my case I use prepared statement so it looks more like that:
case when ?=1 then ?

Comment: @EliGolin:- You can in that case resolve your error by casting the text date with timestamp.

Comment: Please look at my comment to @a_horse_with_no_name